# MVC5 Ajax.ActionLink Loads New Page Instead of Replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink, html.actionlink

*I know that similar questions have been asked and answered multiple times; for the life of me I cannot determine what I am missing, please bear with me.*

I am trying to load a partial view with an editor for an item on the page, and display that editor as a Bootstrap modal, but it always loads to a new page.

`_Layout.cshtml` references the jQuery bundle:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

`BundleConfig.RegisterBundles() adds jQuery and unobtrusive ajax:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js") // <-- must come first
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min"));
```

The `Scripts` folder contains both files:

[image: Scripts Folder screenshot showing both files]

The `View` has an empty `div` with the correct `id` to receive the content

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

I have constructed the `ActionLink` thusly:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(linkText: "Edit",
    actionName: "GetEditor",
    routeValues: new {id = Model.Id},
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "showEditor",
        UpdateTargetId = "editor",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    })
```

My JS function just shows the modal:

```
function showEditor() { $("#editor").modal("show"); };
```

... and just to see if I can get it to work, I'm returning a simple string from my Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetEditor(string id) => Content("Success");
```

#### Edit 1

In my web.config I have enabled both client side validation and unobtrusive js:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

#### Edit 2

I have tried to refresh without using the cache (`Ctrl+F5`) with the same result, and the dev tools show no JavaScript errors.  I am getting the same results across all browsers.

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Turns out I'm just an idiot:

I tried to add the unobtrusive validation library manually:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

... and it started working.  I then thought maybe something was wrong with the bundling - although I was very careful to keep the libraries in the right order....

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
  .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js") 
  .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min"));  // <--- what's missing?
```

Turns out, **full names for javascript files are required**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> Ctrl + F5

To refresh your page and try again.

For Chrome may cached your bundled resources.

Press `F12` and view if there exists any JavaScript error and fix it if any.

Try returning a `PartialView` as the result in your C# action.

Comment: `Ctrl+F5` refresh did not help, and there are no errors in the dev tools.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled it in the web.config?

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: Or enabled it through the HTML Helper

```
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for reminding me to check that; I've added it to the question.